# ES6 Class inherit / extend flow type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

My flow type looks like this:

```
type ModalTypes{
 id: number,
 name: string
}
```

I would like to inherit the type definition for my class and also reuse it in the constructor:

```
class Modal extends ModalTypes {
  constructor(data: ModalTypes) {
    super()
    this.id = data.id
    this.name = data.name
  }
}
```

Sadly that doesn't work. I know that I can only extend a class but how can I add some type definitions to my class.

 I don't want to write duplicate code like this:

```
class Modal{
  id: number
  name: string
  constructor(data: {id: number, name: string}) {
    super()
    this.id = data.id
    this.name = data.name
  }
}
```

Here I am adding `id` and `name` twice, once to the Modal class and once to the constructor. 
 I want to add it only once and prevent duplications.

Comment: A type is just a compiler thing. Classes are part of the transpiled code. Therefore youcant use types as superclasses as they dont exist in the code.

Comment: Don't inherit to prevent duplicate properties that is inheritance misuse IMHO. What should drive inheritance IMHO is if Modal **is** ModalType. If yes than inheritance makes sense but if not then don't inherit.

Comment: yeah, right @Nope, I don't need to inherit. But I want to use the same types without defining them in the class and constructor. I would like to define them in just one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance isn't really what you need in this instance, even if it might save some typing (no pun intended!)

You can use the utility `$PropertyType<>` to avoid mismatching types and ensuring consistency at least.

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSgSwBMAuKAOwFcBbAIwjgBpdyBDKiU5YOfMgc2wBfbNgDGAGxbJUAWQSEW4rMyKkAJPCT1QAFXAQAPJpQMoAciJmAfMzJsOUDYkhxd+o8+Smzd9teZ4zKIIZFxwFKLACHAAFArALKTGyACUynh4wAAW+MgAdEToUPEsBYQBUNm5eb7QGCU19hlQzMJCQA))

```
type Props = {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

class Modal {
  id: $PropertyType<Props, 'id'>
  name: $PropertyType<Props, 'name'>

  constructor(data: Props) {
    this.id = data.id
    this.name = data.name    
  }

}
```

It's a shame that flow doesn't support spread at class level, like it does at type level, it would save some keyboard time.  An alternative approach might be to not extract the properties at class level, but leave them in an object property, thus:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSgSwBMAuKAOwFcBbAIwjgBpdyBDKiU5YOfMgc2wBfbNgDGAGxbJUAWQSEW4rMzCIUpeEmTMozUQjJc4FUcARwAFKq0a1yAJTKAkMAAW+ZADprKdFB-aeMKCQA))

```
type Props = {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

class Modal {
  props: Props

  constructor(props: Props) {
    this.props = props
  }
}
```

Of course this means more fingerwork whenever you want to access the properties, and may not be what you want in terms of 'own properties' on the object.  With the latter approach, you might even be able to use Generics to make reusable classes, which might have some value.

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSgSwBMAuKAOwFcBbAIwjgBpdyBDKiU5YOfMgc2wBfbNgDGAGxbJUAWQSEW4gDwAVAHxZmYRClIrmUZqIRkucCqOAI4ACm1JkegJSaAkMAAW+ZADp7KdCh-ZGZhYTETLigqeUVSOQVleAcNDDIIAHcoBMUbTAISKABGBlZ2UgByGgQaCqhBJ2wgA))

```
type Props = {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

class Modal<T> {
  props: T

  constructor(props: T) {
    this.props = props
  }
}

const modal: Modal<Props> = new Modal({ id: 1, name: 'bob' })
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change your type to:

```
 class ModalTypes {
   id: number,
   name: string
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to do only some type checking without introducing a new class. Is this possible?
It doesn't need to be a superclass, the class should only be able to have the same types as the type ModalTypes (thereby it should not duplicate the types in constructor and class)